# RabbitMQ Multiple Listeners for same Event

Tags: rabbitmq, asp.net-core-2.2

I have an event named CompanyUpdated that gets raised each time when a company profile is updated.
I need two listeners to listen to this event . One for search service to update its data for Azure Search and another for Updating the company details in Catalog Management.

Can I create two listeners to listen to this event?

Also, is it possible to name the two listeners with the same name in two different microservices?

Answer (score 1):

Rabbit MQ supports pub-sub. You should create two queues and use an exchange that will route the message to two queues (like fanout exchange). Then the listener for Azure Search should listen to one queue, and Catalog Management Listener should listen to another queue.

This will guarantee that both listeners will get the event.

I can't comment much on asp.net since I don't have any experience with the .Net platform.
However, you can read [Pub-Sub implementation tutorial for C#](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-three-dotnet.html) for more details.